# How can I use this macro in cases that I don't want to pass function as argument?

Tags: c, macros

given the following Macro in C:

```
#define helper(arg1, arg2, func) do {\
if ((arg1) == (arg2)) {(arg1)++; (arg2)++;}\
func((arg1));\
} while (0)
```

If sometimes I don't want to pass func as argument to the macro, how can I call to the macro?
Namely, I want to call to macro like that: `helper(x,y,?);` such then the line `func(arg1);` (in the macro) will not be executed. But I don't know how can i do it and what I need to pass to the macro instead of `?` ..

Is there a way/trick to do is with the above macro?

I thought to write dummy function like that:

```
void dummy_function(int arg) { return; }
```

and to use that in these cases `helper(x,y,dummy_function)`. But I looking for another and more elegant trick if there is one. without the need to write such a function.

Comment: There's a simple solution: Create a *function* and pass a `NULL` pointer for `func` if it shouldn't be used or called. That macro is just bad, without type-safety, and it could break quite badly by small mistakes in its usage.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yes, I thought about that. you can see that I edited before some secs my question. But I looking for more elegant trick (without the need to write more function) if exists.. And regarding the macro, this is not the point of my question..

Comment: Function-like macros should almost always be implemented as actual function instead. If you want the code to be inlined then add the `inline` specifier as a hint (or just let the compiler decide on its own how to optimize the code, which it will do much better than most of us).

Comment: you can use `#define dummy_function(...)`

Comment: @user253751 nicer. But there is no type of "sinkhole" so that if I pass it as a "function" it won't do anything to the parameters it will receive? (something like: /dev/null or something like that..)

Comment: in the standard library? of course not, why would anyone want a function that does nothing? :)

Comment: @user253751 for example , it would have been fine if when I pass NULL as a function and I do NULL(arg1,arg2,...); Then nothing will happen and it will be ok.  don't you think so?

Comment: Define "elegant". Is it too obvious to have `another_helper(x,y)` that only takes two parameters?

Comment: You can pass `(void)` as the third argument just as it is now.  That will be treated as a throw-away type cast instead of a function call.  Alternatively, you can define a macro that discards its argument and pass that as the third argument.

Comment: @MathQues if that would compile, it would crash because it would call the function code at address 0 which is not a valid address

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:** Macros for such purpose are questionable, a way better solution is using functions instead, they provide way better type safety and other andvantages – how to deal with see [Lundin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/584518/lundin)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73472045/1312382)!

You could simply pass a cast to `void` as function argument:

```
helper(someVariable, anotherOne, (void));
```

If you want to have it a bit more convenient you could help out with a variadic macro:

```
#define helper(...) helper_(__VA_ARGS__, (void), )
// final empty token prevents empty __VA_ARGS__ within helper_ (!)

#define helper_(arg1, arg2, function, ...) // ...
```

though this comes with the disadvantage that surplus arguments simply are discarded (while passing too view would be evaluated to `((void))++` and thus would fail to compile).

Beware, too, that this would fail, too, on MSVC, as this one incorrectly interprets the variadic arguments as one single token.

Comment: I posted an alternative which will not allow surplus arguments.

Comment: @Lundin Fully agree – the function is the *way* better approach ;)

Comment: Sure, but apart from that obvious solution that I think most would agree is the best, further down in the answer I came up with a handy little macro trick, passing `__VA_ARGS__` to a struct initializer list. It's not 100% bullet proof either, but solves a lot of problems with incorrect number of arguments and type conversions.

Comment: @Lundin Quite my doubts if that's worth the effort any more – passing `NULL` is pretty clear and expresses *do nothing* just as nicely as not passing any argument at all – even more explicitly...

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: macros like these are a terrible idea and you should seriously consider writing a function like

```
void func (int* arg1, int* arg2, void(*func)(int) );
```

where `func` is set to `NULL` when not used. Or alternatively as someone suggested, pass on a function that does nothing. All of that is perfectly fine design.

Macros or not, you definitely need to drop the idea of passing a variable seemingly by value and then have that one changed. That's completely unexpected by any C programmer - don't go inventing some private macro language very different from C.

---

As for how to *not* do it properly with macros, like you asked... here is one way which is fairly type safe despite being an evil macro:

- Make a variadic macro.
- It is handy to use compound literals inside macros to create temporary objects that will get optimized away.
- We could invent an internal struct type corresponding to your macro argument list, then initialize it using the variadic macro list `__VA_ARGS__`. This gives a bit of type safety since argument types must match the struct and the number of arguments can't be more than the number of struct members.
- Initializer lists need to init all members of a struct but can leave some blank, solving the ambiguity with the number of parameters passed.

Example:

```
typedef struct
{
  int* arg1;
  int* arg2;
  void (*func) (int);
} internal_struct;

#define helper(...)                                        \
do {                                                       \
  if( *(internal_struct){__VA_ARGS__}.arg1 ==              \
      *(internal_struct){__VA_ARGS__}.arg2 )               \
  {                                                        \
    ++*(internal_struct){__VA_ARGS__}.arg1;                \
    ++*(internal_struct){__VA_ARGS__}.arg2;                \
  }                                                        \
  (internal_struct){__VA_ARGS__}.func &&                   \
  ((internal_struct){__VA_ARGS__}.func(*(internal_struct){__VA_ARGS__}.arg1),1); \
} while(0)
```

Here the internal struct compound literal will either get `func` set to a function pointer, if one is passed, or to NULL (by the static storage initialization rules) if it isn't. We can check this with the `&&` operator which guarantees left op evaluation before right op. So if it isn't NULL, execute the function.

Now as it happens the function in this example used `void` result and we can't have that in a && expression. Hence the trick to use the comma operator first to execute the function, then pass on the dummy value `1` to keep the `&&` operator happy.

Full example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct
{
  int* arg1;
  int* arg2;
  void (*func) (int);
} internal_struct;

#define helper(...)                                        \
do {                                                       \
  if( *(internal_struct){__VA_ARGS__}.arg1 ==              \
      *(internal_struct){__VA_ARGS__}.arg2 )               \
  {                                                        \
    ++*(internal_struct){__VA_ARGS__}.arg1;                \
    ++*(internal_struct){__VA_ARGS__}.arg2;                \
  }                                                        \
  (internal_struct){__VA_ARGS__}.func &&                   \
  ((internal_struct){__VA_ARGS__}.func(*(internal_struct){__VA_ARGS__}.arg1),1); \
} while(0)


void do_something (int arg)
{
  printf("do something with %d\n", arg);
}

int main (void)
{
  int x=1;
  int y=1;

  helper(&x, &y, do_something);
  printf("x: %d, y: %d\n", x, y);
  helper(&x, &y);
  printf("x: %d, y: %d\n", x, y);
}
```

Output:

```
do something with 2
x: 2, y: 2
x: 3, y: 3
```

Generated disassembly on gcc x86 -O3:

```
main:
    sub     rsp, 8
    mov     edi, 2
    call    do_something
    mov     edx, 2
    mov     esi, 2
    xor     eax, eax
    mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC1
    call    printf
    mov     edx, 3
    mov     esi, 3
    xor     eax, eax
    mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC1
    call    printf
    xor     eax, eax
    add     rsp, 8
    ret
```

As you can see, the compound literals yield absolutely no overhead.